# How to fill array class member from array parameter in constructor

Tags: c#

I created two classes, the first is named `Author` and the second `Book`. 
In the `Book` class, I have the following attributes:

`private string s_titre;
 private string[] name_author;
 private double d_Price;`

and the following constructor:

```
public Book(string title, Author[] author, double price)
{
    this.s_titre = titre;
    for (int i = 0; i <auteur.Length; i++)
    {
         authoritarianism[i] = auteur[i].name;
    }
    this.d_price = price;
}
```

I don't know how to fill the field `author` from `Author`.
I tried the above code, but it didn't work.

Comment: It's worth being aware that those are *fields*. Attributes in C# mean something entirely different. It doesn't help that we don't know what the `Author` class does...

Comment: Do you get an exception? What is auteur, is this an array as well? Perhaps auteur is empty?

Comment: It looks like you have a lot of typos in your code, I assume `auteur` is supposed to be `author`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you forgot to create the array first?

```
public Book(string title, Author[] author, double price)
{
    this.s_titre = titre;
    // create an array of the same length as author
    authoritarianism = new string[author.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i <auteur.Length; i++)
    {
         authoritarianism[i] = auteur[i].name;
    }
    this.d_price = price;
}
```

Comment: please i want to stock auther[i].name in name_author . i hope understund me.

Comment: Well then just change `authoritarianism` to `name_author`, I'm just confused what is what in your code

Comment: can you give me your email to send you the code . thank you

Comment: when i do this he display me 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: no I won't send you my email, just post your code in your question. This error means that you are modyfing your array before creating it. You create arrays by doing `name_author = new string[...]`, just like I did in my answer

Comment: thank you very much it working know i want to display the information in method i try with this                                                                                          string x;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
               x= this.s_titre + " de " + this.s_nomAuteur[i] + " et " + this.s_nomAuteur[i+1] + " ,coute " + this.d_prix + " DH avec " + this.i_quantité_en_stock + " exemplaires en stock ";
           return x;}

Answer (score 0):

The reason the code did not work is that the array inside the class has not been initialized. You can initialize and copy an array (in fact, any `IEnumerable<T>`) with LINQ:

```
public Book(string title, IEnumerable<Author> author, double price) {
    s_titre = titre;
    d_price = price;
    authoritarianism = author.ToArray();
}
```

> **Edit:** I want to store `auther[i].name` in `name_author[i]`

Add a call of `Select` to the chain:

```
author_names = author.Select(a => a.Name).ToArray()
```